# Scala - Option Type Var Manipulation

Tags: scala, scala-option

I am working on an online exercise practicing Options and threads, both of which I have very little experience.  The online exercise comes with a test suite, so right now I am trying to get my Option test cases to pass before I move on to the thread test cases.

Here is my code:

```
case class BankAccount() {
  def getBalance = account.balance

  def incrementBalance(amount: Int): Option[Int] = {
    account.balance = Some(account.balance.get + amount)
    getBalance
  }

//  def closeAccount(): Option[Int] = {
//    account.balance = None: Option[Int]
//  }
}

object account {
  var balance = Some(0)
}
```

I have `closeAccount()` commented out because it is currently giving me an error saying that it is expecting type `Some[Int] instead of Option[Int]`. Understandable considering how I have initialized `balance`. I am not sure how to go from a value of `Some[Int]` to `None` as seen in `closeAccount()`.

Any help would be appreciated in getting this figured out.  Thank you in advance.

**First Edit:  I figured out what stupid mistake I was making with `incrementBalance`.  Since `getBalance` was a `val`, it wasn't recalculating the value after manipulation.  Still lost on `closeAccount()` though.**

Comment: Note that account.balance.get will throw an exception if balance is None (this call essentially kills the purpose of using Option). You would better use Option as a monad in incrementBalance, e.g., account.balance.map(_ + amount)

Comment: I did run into the issue!  I refactored my code later on to use a `case switch` to check if it was `Some[Int]` or `None`.  Thank you though for your suggestion, as well :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var balance = Some(0)` is inferred to be of type `Some[Int]`, when you need to tell this explicitly that it's of type `Option[Int]`:

```
var balance: Option[Int] = Some(0)
```

Then `balance` will be able to take in either `Some(0)` or `None`.

By the way, it's sometimes a good practice to always use `Option(...)` instead of `Some(...)`. This is because `Some(null)` will become `Some(null)` whereas `Option(null)` will become `None` which is what we usually want.

Comment: Simple enough and a silly oversight on my behalf. Thanks for the suggestions.  It worked around that issue, but still have some stuff to tamper with it seems now that I've dealt with that.